# Django : Problem with updating object from the model "already exist"?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am new to web developing and to Django. I have difficulties to find the right way to update a record (object) of my model in my Django project.Can you have a look on my code and help me to fix it ?
After running the code below I got the errors that the object already exist.  ( yes , and should be , I want to update it !!!) My guess is the is_valid()  is the problem.

I have the following  model:

```python
class  QA_machine_DB(models.Model):

    QAmachine = models.CharField( max_length = 64, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32,null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %  (self.id)
```

I have the following view:

```python
def formreport(request):
    Booking= BookingForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if Booking.is_valid():
            print('############## VALIDATION  GOOD ######################### ')
            machine_name= Booking['QAmachine']
            print('Name',Booking.cleaned_data['QAmachine'])
            print("Status: ",Booking.cleaned_data['status'])

            to_book =QA_machine_DB.objects.get(QAmachine= machine_name)  # if I hard code the machine_name  it works . !?  I guess is_valid is the problem .... 
            #to_book =QA_machine_DB.objects.get(QAmachine= 'ali' )
            to_book.status='free'
            to_book.save()

            return index(request)
        else:
            print('Form not valid', Booking.errors)


    return render(request,'QA_interface_app/form_page.html', { 'Booking': Booking})
```

I really don't see it , if you can help me I would be fantastic . Thanks in advance

Comment: please show us the full stack-trace

Comment: Form not valid <ul class="errorlist"><li>QAmachine<ul class="errorlist"><li>Q a_machine_db with this QAmachine already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>
[02/Sep/2018 10:28:44] "POST /QA_machines_app/form_page/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1239

Comment: Please edit your question. Btw this probably means you are trying to insert a `QA_machine_DB` with a name that already exists in your database.

Comment: hope that you you mean with full stack trace ....

Comment: You probably haven't passed `id` in `request.POST` data.

Comment: hum , I used the forms.ModelForm  and the class Meta to make my form there is no id  input possible. How should I do to pass the id ?

Comment: I change my model now and put one of the field explicitly primary_key,so that I got it in my Form and in my request.POST . I still have the save problem: with an existing object I don't get trough the is_valid  whereas it fine with a new  obejct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try change:

```
to_book =QA_machine_DB.objects.get(QAmachine= machine_name)
```

on

```
to_book =QA_machine_DB.objects.get(QAmachine=Booking.cleaned_data['QAmachine'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately , it does not work.  It doesn't go through the the is_valid() function and I got exactly the same error.     I really guess it has something to do with the is_valid.   When i hard code it  to go through the is_valid() I gave the form something that not existing for ( in ) the model .

Answer (score 0):

First , I didn't make it through the is_valid() but I find a work around and it is enough at the moment for my project :

```python
    if request.method == 'POST':

    post_request_dict = (dict(request.POST)) # get the query set into dict
    #  then I use the data to do the update.  
    print('++++++  PK ++++++:',post_request_dict['QAmachine'][0])
    TT=QA_machine_DB.objects.get(QAmachine=post_request_dict['QAmachine'][0])
    TT.status=post_request_dict['status'][0]
    TT.save()

    if Booking.is_valid():

        return index(request)
    else:
        print('Form not valid', Booking.errors)
```

It is quit ugly but it works ...  with pk or the instance in the form it  did not work for me. 
Please let me know  for alternative ....